# Remove apostrophes from json string property

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Hi I try deserialize this string with JSON.NET.

String look like this:

```
{
    "mishelka.sk": {
        "idUser": 15289422,
        "nick": "MiShelKa.Sk",
        "photo": "1",
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 4,
        "videoAlbums": 3,
        "sefNick": "mishelka.sk",
        "profilPercent": 78,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 14,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1528/94/n_15289422.jpg?v=4",
            "medium": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1528/94/m_15289422.jpg?v=4",
            "24x24": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1528/94/s_15289422.jpg?v=4"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "10",
            "regionName": "zahraničie",
            "idCity": "182",
            "cityName": "Zahraničie - GB"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": false,
            "isChating": false,
            "idChat": 0,
            "roomName": "",
            "lastLogin": 1294767618
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 4,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 1,
            "videoAlbums": 3,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 33,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0,
            "emailNew": 1,
            "postaNew": 0,
            "clubInvitations": 0,
            "dashboardItems": 54
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": "Jaj henka zabila si dneska hah",
            "addTime": "1294678134"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false
    },
    "mishel431": {
        "idUser": 18327105,
        "nick": "mishel431",
        "photo": "1",
        "sex": 2,
        "photoAlbums": 1,
        "videoAlbums": 0,
        "sefNick": "mishel431",
        "profilPercent": 98,
        "emphasis": false,
        "age": 15,
        "isBlocked": false,
        "PHOTO": {
            "normal": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1832/71/n_18327105.jpg?v=5",
            "medium": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1832/71/m_18327105.jpg?v=5",
            "24x24": "http://u.aimg.sk/fotky/1832/71/s_18327105.jpg?v=5"
        },
        "PLUS": {
            "active": false,
            "activeTo": "0000-00-00"
        },
        "LOCATION": {
            "idRegion": "1",
            "regionName": "Banskobystrický kraj",
            "idCity": "70",
            "cityName": "Lučenec"
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "isLoged": false,
            "isChating": false,
            "idChat": 0,
            "roomName": "",
            "lastLogin": 1294760188
        },
        "PROJECT_STATUS": {
            "photoAlbums": 1,
            "photoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbums": 0,
            "videoAlbumsFavs": 0,
            "videoAlbumsExts": 0,
            "blogPosts": 0,
            "emailNew": 1,
            "postaNew": 0,
            "clubInvitations": 0,
            "dashboardItems": 14
        },
        "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": " I hate "apple" lalala:(",
            "addTime": "1293656085"
        },
        "isFriend": false,
        "isIamFriend": false
    }

}
```

I try deserialize this string into dic everything is ok, but I have one problem.

Here is it:

```
  "STATUS_MESSAGE": {
            "statusMessage": " I hate "apple" lalala:(",
            "addTime": "1293656085"
        },
```

statusMessage property can consit apostrophes,this cause invalid exception json string. I would like elegant remove apostrophs from string property statusMessage in all json string.

Any advice. Use regExp. I am not strong in this domain.

this part is deserialize in this class:

```
  [Export]
public class StatusMessage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Private Fields

    private string _message;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [JsonProperty("statusMessage")]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set
        {
            if (_message != value)
            {
                _message = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("addTime")]
    public string AddTime { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: @user572844 The character you refer to is a 'quotation mark' or 'double quote'.

Comment: Also, what is generating the JSON, it is flawed.

Comment: this json is not generated be me

Comment: Whatever is generating that JSON is dangerously wrong, it allows end users to inject arbitrary commands. If you `eval` it, end users will be able to take over your server. Don't use it.

Comment: re:Dour High Arch
First, thank for advice, It’s our school project, please can you give me example what you mean with :inject arbitrary commands?? SQL injection, it’s possible?

Comment: If you're sending the content of `statusMessage` to a database SQL injection is certainly possible. What if the message was: Little Bobby " }} DROP TABLE "Students"; /*

Comment: But, how can you get table name from my DB ?

Answer (score 2):

The generator of your Json string should escape the quotes using backslash.
Check out the spec on [Json](http://www.json.org/) website  That way you don't have to worry about wrongly formed Json string

Comment: I can’t make any change on this json string, because it is response on http get reqeust on server which isn’t my.